# how to display image on web page from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display images on my php web page from mysql database where i have give the path of my images. but Its only displaying the path but not the image.
I used the following Code:

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $conn= mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("ek",$conn);//EK is my Database
    $sql="select Pics from images";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $image = $row['Pics'];
    print $image;
 ?>
```

and the output I am getting is :

images/DSC01750.jpg

Some body can you please help me to actually displaying the image but not the path.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in an img tag.

```
echo "<img src=\"$image\">";
```

To display several images

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$conn= mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ek",$conn);//EK is my Database
$sql="select Pics from images";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$i=0; 
$display_num =4;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i++ < $display_num){
  $image = $row['Pics'];
  echo "<img src=\"$image\">";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working now but only problem is that its only displaying one image at a time if I  have to display 10 images at a time what should I do then?

Comment: You should loop through your resultset. I'll add the code to the answer.

Comment: I missed the $ before i++, should be $i++. But I added that into the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help but its still displaying only single image but not all images from database

Comment: It should work. Perhaps you could try checking the size of your result set ( echo mysql_num_rows($result) )?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to display an image in an HTML page, you can construct the image tag like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

If you are attempting to obscure the location of an image and serve it via the PHP script, your image tag will look something like this:

```
<img src="yourscript.php" />
```

and you can modify your script to open and output the file:

```
$image = $row['Pics'];
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
readfile( $image );
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$row['Pics']` contains the path to the image, then you'll need to translate that into an image reference to direct the browser to that path.  Something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

Note that "path" can mean something entirely different here.  If it's a server-side fully qualified path, you'll want to translate it into an application-relative path usable by the browser.  Something that begins with `/usr/web/something/blah/` won't be useful to the browser.